# Changing output audio device of other Win32 applications?

Tags: windows, winapi, audio, volume

I want to write a program that allows you to select the output audio device (based on currently connected devices) used by other applications on an individual basis. (E.g. Winamp to my headphones, VLC to my speakers, etc).

The program would (probably) be written in C++ for Vista/7. Most likely I'll try to use the Windows sound APIs, but not sure where to start, or if the whole attempt is futile. (seeing the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791361/controlling-the-volume-of-other-applications) made me doubtful)

I'm not new to writing code, and this isn't a "please do my homework" request, *but I am new to windows code* and was having trouble finding much documentation on anything like this.

Is this possible? Where would you start with this? Do you know of any projects that have already done this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Each application can choose to use the default or a specific device. I don't think anything can choose on it's behalf though as it may have already opened a communication with the device.