# How to get the name of application(s) currently playing audio with powershell using NAudio?

Tags: windows, powershell, audio, .net-assembly

I'm trying to get the name of applications that are actively playing audio in Windows 11 using the [NAudio library](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio).
I'm using the latest official precompiled NAudio.dll v.1.9 as I could not get it working with the latest nuget package 2.2.1.
With this code I can get the playback devices info but the Audio Sessions are always empty.

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\NAudio.dll"
$devices = (New-Object -TypeName NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDeviceEnumerator).EnumerateAudioEndPoints([NAudio.CoreAudioApi.DataFlow]::Render, [NAudio.CoreAudioApi.DeviceState]::Active)
foreach ($device in $devices) {
    Write-Host "Device: $($device.FriendlyName)"
    $sessions = $device.AudioSessionManager2.Sessions
    Write-Host "Number of sessions: $($sessions.Count)"
    foreach ($session in $sessions) {
        Write-Host "Session: $($session.DisplayName)"
        Write-Host "Is Muted: $($session.SimpleAudioVolume.Mute)"
        Write-Host "Volume: $($session.SimpleAudioVolume.Volume)"
    }
}
```

Terminal output:

```
Device: Sound Blaster Z (Sound Blaster Z)
Number of sessions: 0
```

I did read the questions where people were able to get audio sessions using C# but I was hoping to be able to do the same in PowerShell.

- [C# Get list of audio processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52030208/c-sharp-get-list-of-audio-processes)
- [How to get audio session GUID with Windows API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65441145/how-to-get-audio-session-guid-with-windows-api)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why downloading the latest package from Nuget didn't work for you is because the [`NAudio` Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NAudio) has a bunch of dependencies (including the `NAudio.CoreAudioApi` Namespace, where [the `MMDeviceEnumerator` Class exists](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/94f4ea64765c041d3df2feef774e856aefff5b39/NAudio.Wasapi/CoreAudioApi/MMDeviceEnumerator.cs#L33-L151)).

---

Specifically, the `MMDeviceEnumerator` class exists in [`NAudio.Wasapi` Pacakage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NAudio.Wasapi):

```bash
PS ..\pwsh> [NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDeviceEnumerator].Assembly

Version    Name               PublicKeyToken    Target Culture
-------    ----               --------------    ------ -------
2.2.1.0    NAudio.Wasapi      e279aa5131008a41  MSIL   neutral
```

---

Ideally, `Install-Package` should be able to handle dependencies for you (unsure on this, my experience with this cmdlet is really bad - *see other option using the `dotnet` CLI below*):

```bash
Install-Package NAudio -Version 2.2.1
```

Another option to download the assemblies is to use the [dotnet CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/), available when installing the [.NET SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download). I personally use this:

```bash
try {
    $framework = 'netstandard2.0'
    $packagename = 'NAudio'
    dotnet new classlib -f $framework -o "$packagename.package"
    Push-Location "$packagename.package"
    dotnet add package $packagename
    dotnet publish --configuration Release -o lib
}
finally {
    Pop-Location
}
```

You should have all required assemblies after:

[image: deps]

Lastly, using the `2.2.1` version of this package, the following code should list all processes using an audio device.

```bash
try {
    Add-Type -Path .\NAudio.package\lib\*.dll
    $deviceEnumerator = [NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDeviceEnumerator]::new()
    $audioEndPoints = $deviceEnumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(
        [NAudio.CoreAudioApi.DataFlow]::Render,
        [NAudio.CoreAudioApi.DeviceState]::Active)

    $result = $audioEndPoints | ForEach-Object {
        $sessions = $_.AudioSessionManager.Sessions

        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $sessions.Count; $i++) {
            $session = $sessions[$i]
            # Idle process, we can skip this
            if ($session.GetProcessID -eq 0) {
                continue
            }

            [pscustomobject]@{
                Device             = $_.FriendlyName
                ProcessId          = $session.GetProcessID
                ProcessDisplayName = (Get-Process -Id $session.GetProcessID).ProcessName
                State              = $session.State
                IsMuted            = $session.SimpleAudioVolume.Mute
                Volume             = $session.SimpleAudioVolume.Volume
            }

            $session.Dispose()
        }

        $_.Dispose()
    }
}
finally {
    if ($deviceEnumerator) {
        $deviceEnumerator.Dispose()
    }
}

# Here is the output:
$result
```

You could filter this output for those objects where the `.State` property is equal to `AudioSessionState.AudioSessionStateActive` to find only those processes reproducing audio at the moment.

```bash
$result | Where-Object {
    $_.State -eq [NAudio.CoreAudioApi.Interfaces.AudioSessionState]::AudioSessionStateActive
}
```

Comment: This works beautifully, I cannot thank you enough. Marking as solved!

Comment: @ChrisP glad it helped. Out of curiosity, how did you download all depency dlls ? `Install-Package` ?

Comment: I used your code for the dotnet CLI which put them all in one folder for the first time. Now that I have it working it only seems to need NAudio.Wasapi.dll to function but having them all in separate folders before made working out which dlls were needed a lot trickier.

Comment: @ChrisP gotcha. good to know