# How to fetch a nuget package for stand-alone use?

Tags: powershell, nuget

I know how to use a nuget's various wrappers to fetch dependencies for an application.

However, sometimes I just want to get a package from nuget, and its dependencies, in a way that makes it ready-to-use.  So basically, a way to fetch a Nuget package and its dependencies in a way that the nuget package can *access* its dependencies, instead of expecting the consumer to bundle them all together into the bin folder.

Is there a nuget tool that supports this workflow?

Because simple cases like "I want to write a simple script that uses dotnet objects in this nuget package" will fail, as my script calls `nuget install examplePackageWithDependencies -o ./packages` it will have `examplePackageWithDependencies` present in `.\Packages\examplePackageWithDependencies.1.0.0\lib\` but its hypothetical dependent package `dependencyPackage` will be in `.\Packages\dependencyPackage.1.0.0\lib\`.

So if I write script code in eg csx or powershell that interacts with `examplePackageWithDependencies.dll`, or even just cmd code if package `examplePackageWithDependencies` includes an .exe (this happens), it will fail because `.\Packages\dependencyPackage.1.0.0\lib\` isn't in its module search path.

So I'm wondering, is there a recommended approach for this workflow?  Or is dumping all the files into one folder something I should just DIY?

Because I can't find it in the nuget docs.

Comment: I personally use the dotnet CLI for this, creating a dummy classlib -> add package -> publish. Example in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77276619/15339544